# Listener callback functions

Tags: c++, c++11

I wrote codes that listener and callback function like this:

```
struct MyListener
{
    virtual void callback1(int value) = 0;
    virtual void callback2(string value) = 0;
    ...
};
```

```
vector<weak_ptr<MyListener>> _listeners;

void MyClass::fireCallback1(int value)
{
    vector<weak_ptr<MyListener>>::iterator iter = _listeners.begin();
    while (iter != _listeners.end())
    {
        if ((*iter).expired())
        {
            iter = _listeners.erase(iter);
        }
        else
        {
            shared_ptr<MyListener> listener = (*iter).lock();
            listener->callback1(value);
            ++iter;
        }
    }
}

void MyClass::fireCallback2(string value)
{
    vector<weak_ptr<MyListener>>::iterator iter = _listeners.begin();
    while (iter != _listeners.end())
    {
        if ((*iter).expired())
        {
            iter = _listeners.erase(iter);
        }
        else
        {
            shared_ptr<MyListener> listener = (*iter).lock();
            listener->callback2(value);
            ++iter;
        }
    }
}
```

But as you see, when I add more functions on `MyListener` struct, I have to add `fireCallbackN` functions on `MyClass`, and it has too many duplicated codes.

Is there best way to make simplify these duplicate codes in C++?

Comment: Templates? Create one callback interface which has a single method that takes a templates type.

Comment: This is better asked on stackoverflow. But you can simply pass the function as one of the parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
struct MyListener
{
    virtual void on_data(int value) = 0;    // same function name
    virtual void on_data(string value) = 0; // same function name
    ...
};

template<typename T>
void MyClass::trigger_data_event(T&& value) // pass by universal reference
{
    auto iter = _listeners.begin(); // consider using auto where appropriate

    while (iter != _listeners.end())
    {
        // don't use expired here: it involves concurrency issues if the pointer
        // is invalidated between calling expired and lock

        // instead, just lock() and check the result:

        if(auto p = iter->lock())
        {
            p->on_data(std::forward<T>(value)); // works with both callbacks
            ++iter;
        }
        else
            iter = _listeners.erase(iter);
    }
}
```

I renamed the APIs you used from callback1/2 to on_data (same name) and unified the implementations of fireCallback1 and fireCallback2.

Comment: thx utnapistim, I made a working template code referred your source.